# Until loop but how to timeout if it fails after 5 mintues

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have this 2 until in bash:

```
until grep "1" /var/tmp/machineip > /dev/null;
do
    nova list --name spawningtestwin|grep spawningtestwin|awk -F= '{print $2}'|awk '{print $1}'|sed 's/ //g' > /var/tmp/machineip
done

mip=$(cat /var/tmp/machineip)
until ping -c1 $mip &>/dev/null; do :; done
```

How can I limit the until to 5 minutes? If it doesn't get anything in 5 minutes it should stop.

Comment: Perhaps you could use [timeout(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html). Or (thru `ulimit` builtin) [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_CPU`

Comment: It is not clear what `nova` is doing

Comment: Don't worry about nova, that is just spinup a virtual machine. Just focus on the loop, how can I limit this loop run only until 5 minutes. Timout is good for command but not for loop.

Comment: You could use `timeout` on a script containing only the loop. And if you care about CPU time, you could use `ulimit` at start of your script

Comment: You can also compute yourself the remaining real wall-clock time in the loop. Use [date(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) with `%s` and some shell arithmetic

Comment: There are several notions of time on Linux. Be sure to read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). So "limit the time to 5 minutes" is not precise enough

Answer (score 1):

TIMEOUT=0 ; until ping -c1 $mip &>/dev/null || test "$TIMEOUT" -gt "$((5*60))" ; do :; sleep 1 ; TIMEOUT=$((TIMEOUT+1)) ; done

You can change 5 to the number of minutes you like.

Answer (score 1):

`timeout` is likely a good option, but since you are trying to run a loop it might require a bit more syntax than you want. If that's what you prefer, I'm sure we can work up an example.

If you want to do it the old-fashioned way...

```
declare -i now start=$(date +%s) # linux epoch timestamp in seconds
timeout=300                      # 300s = 5m
until grep -q "1" /var/tmp/machineip 
do now=$(date +%s)               # linux epoch timestamp in seconds
   if (( ( now - start ) < timeout )) # less than 5m
   then nova list --name spawningtestwin |
          awk -F= '/spawningtestwin/ {
             gsub(/ +//,"",$2);
             print $2
          }'                             > /var/tmp/machineip
          sleep 20
   else echo taking too much time.
        exit 1
   fi
done
```

`awk` not my forté. you guys please check me on this...

In particular, `awk -F= '{print $2}'|awk '{print $1}'` makes no sense to me. In *general*, any time multiple *simple* calls to `awk`, `sed`, and/or `grep` are pipelined it makes me think most of them could be eliminated.